# .NET XML: What is the .NET equivalent of XmlDocument.TransformNode?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

In native programming the IXMLDOMDocument2 object had a [`tranformNode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms896487.aspx) method:

```
public BSTR transformNode(IXMLDOMNode stylesheet);
```

So in the end I could transform an XML document using:

```
public string TransformDocument(IXMLDOMDocument2 doc, IXMLDOMDocument2 stylesheet)
{
   return doc.TransformNode(stylesheet);
}
```

I'm trying to find the managed equivalent. I've already discovered [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) object:

```
public string TransformDocument(XmlDocument doc, XmlDocument stylesheet)
{
   //return doc.TransformNode(stylesheet); //TransformNode not supported
}
```

So what is the managed way to transform xml?

I've stumbled across the **deprecated** [XslTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform.aspx) object, but none of the 18 overloads takes an xml document, or an xml stylesheet.

The replacement Microsoft indicates is the mouthful: [System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx). But like it's deprecated cousin, none of XslCompiledTransform's 14 overloads takes xml in an input parameter.

So what's the accepted method to transform xml in C# .NET 2.0?

Put it another way: complete the following helper method:

```
public string TransformDocument(XmlDocument doc, XmlDocument stylesheet)
{
   //todo: figure out how to transform xml in C#
}
```

---

### Answer

[Waqas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470286/-net-xml-what-is-the-net-equivalent-of-xmldocument-transformnode#470405) had the answer. Here is another, very similar, solution:

```
/// <summary>
/// This method simulates the XMLDOMDocument.TransformNode method
/// </summary>
/// <param name="doc">XML document to be transformed</param>
/// <param name="stylesheet">The stylesheet to transform with</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string Transform(XmlDocument doc, XmlDocument stylesheet)
{
    XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    transform.Load(stylesheet); // compiled stylesheet

    System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    transform.Transform(doc, XmlWriter.Create(writer));

    return writer.ToString();   
}
```

**Note:** If you're a performance weenie, you might want to create an overload to pass the pre-compiled transform, if you're going to transforming more than once.

```
public static string Transform(XmlDocument doc, XslCompiledTransform stylesheet)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functions take IXPathNavigable objects as input (and XmlDoucment/XmlNode classes implement IXPathNavigable).

Here's how it would work:

```
public string TransformDocument(XmlDocument doc, XmlDocument stylesheet)
{
   XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
   transform.Load(stylesheet); // compiled stylesheet
   System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
   transform.Transform(doc, null, writer);
   return writer.ToString();
}
```

Optimizations and improvements:

- Cache the compiled stylesheet if you use it more than once.
- Load the XSL directly into the XslCompiledTransform instead of building an XmlDocument first.
- Use XmlNode instead of XmlDocument to make the function more generic.

Comment: @anonymousstackoverflowuser Sorry about that. Missed an argument. Fixed.

Comment: Answer status regained! i edited question with the option of wrapping the StringWriter *in* an XmlWirter.

Answer (score 0):

First load the XSL and the XML doc.

```
XmlDocument xsldoc = new XmlDocument();
xsldoc.Load(xslfile);

XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(xmlfile);
```

Load the xsl into a transform object.

```
XslCompiledTransform xsldoctrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
xsldoctrans.Load(xsldoc);
```

Transform it into a memorystream that can be read.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
xsldoctrans.Transform(xmldoc, (XsltArgumentList)null, ms);
```

Then get the transformed data:

```
byte[] bTransformeddata = ms.ToArray();
string sTransformeddata = xsldoctrans.OutputSettings.Encoding.GetString(bTransformeddata);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(pathToXmlOrXMLString);

    XslCompiledTransform xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xsl.Load(pathToXsl);

    string result = TransformDocument(doc, xsl);

}

static string TransformDocument(XmlDocument doc, XslCompiledTransform xsl)
{    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        xsl.Transform(doc.CreateNavigator(), null, sw);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use in production code, looks similar to Wolf's, but calls the XslCompiledTransform.Transform method with an XPathDocument (initializable from a string containing XML) and an XmlWriter which directs the output to a StringBuilder.