# Microsoft.XMLDOM.1.0 - "the data necessary to complete this operation is not available"

Tags: powershell, msxml

I'm trying to load a XML with the following code:

```
$xsl = new-object -ComObject Microsoft.XMLDOM.1.0
$xsl.load('http://172.16.177.200/1.xml')
$xsl.transformNode($xsl)
```

However, `$xsl.load` only work if the XML is a local file. With the code above, `transformNode` raises an error "the data necessary to complete this operation is not available"

[image]

Tried to add a `start-sleep 5`, no help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting `$xsl.async = $false` before the `.load()` call.

Comment: After creating the `$xsl` variable, set its `async` property to false: `$xsl.async = $false`. This should have the `load` method wait until finished.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes it worked, please add an answer below. Not sure why start-sleep doesn't work. Without setting async to false, it needs something else to trigger the loading process, weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Microsoft.XMLDOM` has been deprecated for years. In COM land you should use `Msxml2.DOMDocument` (more specifically `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0`). [Related](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/cc507432(v=vs.85)).

With COM XML objects you should also disable asynchronous processing, so that loading/parsing the XML document is completed before the next instruction.

```
$xsl = New-Object -ComObject 'Msxml.DOMDocument.6.0'
$xsl.Async = $false
$xsl.Load('http://172.16.177.200/1.xml')
```

With that said, since PowerShell is built on top of .Net it's recommended to work with .Net rather than COM:

```
$xsl = New-Object Xml
$xsl.Load('http://172.16.177.200/1.xml')
```

In .Net land loading/parsing the XML file is synchronous by default. You will need a replacement for `TransformNode()`, though. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/470286/1630171).